# Already installed Git but VSCode keeps suggesting to download it in Mac

Tags: git, github, commit

I recently changed of laptop and got a Mac. I installed first VSCode and the Git version 2.39.2. However, VSCode Source Control section does not recognizes it but when I search for an extension, it recognises it.

[image: This is what the Source Control section shows]

[image: When looking for an extension it appears I have it installed]

I installed git by the binary installer and after all I deleted it. I don´t know if that affected.

I already tried re-installing git but didn´t work and keeping the installer.
Installed GitLens extension but didn´t work.

How can I solve this and start commiting?

Comment: Maybe it installs Git in its own sandbox?

Comment: I have same issue